# two <class=form-control"> with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I do have a propblem with my angularjs Code.

I have an object which I want to split into two Groups.

The two objects looks something like

```
{
"_embedded": {
    "aspects": [
        {
            "name": "KPIs",
            "holderAssetId": "123",
            "aspectTypeId": "KPIs",
            "aspectTypeName": "KPIs",
            "category": "dynamic",
            "description": "description an. ",
            "variables": [
                {
                    "name": "Availability_Minutes",
                    "dataType": "DOUBLE",
                    "unit": "min",
                    "searchable": false,
                    "length": null,
                    "qualityCode": true,
                    "defaultValue": null
                },
```

and 2nd one:

```
"_embedded": {
        "assets": [
            {
                "assetId": "123",
                "tenantId": "aaa",
                "name": "GA700",
                "etag": 1,
                "externalId": "",
```

Now I want to have two Form-Control. In the first one I can choose aspects.name which will be filtered via ng-repeat out of the object. This works right now. 
But The variable x in my ng-repeat is not transferred to my second form-control. Have a look at the code below.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="choose_asset_form">Asset</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="choose_asset_form" ng-model="selected_assetId">
                <option ng-repeat="x in ctrl.assets" ng-value="x.assetId">
                    {{x.name}}
                </option>
            </select>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="choose_aspect_form">Aspect for {{x.assetId}}</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="choose_aspect_form" ng-model="selected_aspect">
                <option ng-repeat="x in ctrl.asset.aspects" ng-value="x.name">
                    {{x.name}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I can see assets.name in the first Control, but I can not see aspects.name in the second form-control.